# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I'm new to Android programming but not so new to Flutter. So far I have been testing on iOS. Now when I want to test on Android I got this problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:1088 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.4.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.4.10.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:1088 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:1088 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.pom'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:1088 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Since I'm not very familiar with android and its problems, please let me know if there is anything else I need to include here in this question.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All dependency requests in your script end up with the same error

> Connect to 127.0.0.1:1088 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

It may be the case that you have configured your system to use a local proxy server, but it's not actually running on that 1088 port.

Comment: Could you elaborate this, or tell how to fix it?

Answer (score 14):

As the Jcenter() is depracated now in 2021,
You can add the mavencentral in Project Level Gradle as

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Comment: jcenter is deprecated but as per [JFrog's announcement](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) ConanCenter and JCenter will remain available for the time being.